# How to use Id from match.params to object in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Hello i want send Id from match.params to my function mapStateToProp. I know that my code is bad but i wanna show what i want to do. Have a good day.

```
product.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const ProductPage = ({match}) => {



    return ( <h1>Hello World</h1>  );
}

const mapStateToProps=state=>({data:state.forHim.eyeCreamForHim[{match.params.id}]})
export default connect(mapStateToProps , {}) (ProductPage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` function accepts a second argument which are the props of the component:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) =>
  ({ data: state.forHim.eyeCreamForHim[props.match.params.id] })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fix this by use ownProps from mapStateToProps.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const ProductPage = ({match , data}) => {



    return ( <h1>{data.name}</h1>  );
}

const mapStateToProps=(state ,ownProps )=>{
    const index = ownProps.match.params.Id;
    console.log(index)
    return{data:state.forHim.eyeCreamForHim[index]}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps , {}) (ProductPage);
```